# Why I'm getting this error in Ionic 6 and capacitor?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am getting an error when I try to deploy my ionic app on android

The ionic version is 6, capacitor version 6

This app uses Filesystem plugin to save a pdf file.

```
* What went wrong:
[capacitor]         A problem was found with the configuration of task ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugRFile' (type 'GenerateLibraryRFileTask').
[capacitor]         - Type 'GenerateLibraryRFileTask' property 'localResourcesFile' specifies file 'C:\Users\erick\Desktop\KP\apps\beerStation\reports\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\intermediates\local_only_symbol_list\debug\R-def.txt' which doesn't exist.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Possible solutions:
[capacitor]         1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
[capacitor]         2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.
```

Comment: you should add more information to your question. try running these 2 command and add output to your question. 1) `ionic info` 2) `npx cap doctor`

Comment: There is no such thing as capacitor 6. Latest version is 3.0. What i recommend is to delete your node-modules/ and android/ folder manually and do npm install.

Comment: Running in the same issue. Any one solved it?